# phpmailer add more contents to body of email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am brand new to phpmailer.. i have made some progress by creating a simple form that allows users to send emails to our inbox:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="send-mail.php">          
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" tabindex="1">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="trade" placeholder="Your Trade" tabindex="3">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2">
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Contact Number" tabindex="4">
    <textarea id="message" rows="8" name="message" placeholder="Message" tabindex="5"></textarea>
    <div class="grid-col one-whole">
            <button type="submit">Send Your Message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

.php:

```
<?php
require('PHPFiles/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require('PHPFiles/class.smtp.php');
require('PHPFiles/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;    
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = '74.208.5.2';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'info@mydomain.com';           
$mail->Password = '*******';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 25; connect to

$mail->From = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
$mail->FromName = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
$mail->addAddress('info@mydomain.com'); 
$mail->Subject = isset($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : "";
$mail->Body = str_replace("\n",'<br>', $_POST['message']);

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->isHTML(true); 

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

At the moment, the Body of the email contains the contents of the textare field. How can the body contain this, but then also a line break, then, the contents of the number field?

Comment: it's just a string. `$mail->body = 'foo'; $mail->body .= 'bar'` gives you `foobar` as the body.

Comment: @MarcB - the second $mail supposed to have the . infront of the =   ??

Comment: u have error in your str_replace, it should be str_replace('\n','<br>', ...,

Comment: @MarcB - the body should be uppercase B too... but other than that it works

Comment: @fsn - can you explain what the error is??

Comment: you have to use '\n' for your str_replace to work or use "\\n" and escape it, also do like <br />

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this. Make a separate variable for all the data that needs to be in the body of the message.

```
$message = "Name :- " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>" . " Number :- " . $_POST['number'];
$mail->Body = $message;
```

Comment: with the above i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: this does not work, please test your code before submitting

Answer (score 0):

so doing it like:

```
$mail->Body = str_replace('\n','<br />', $_POST['message']);
```

or:

```
$mail->Body = str_replace("\\n","<br />", $_POST["message"]);
```

should fix the problem of string getting the "line breaks".

btw. it`s always good to:

```
var_dump($data);
die();
```

to see what are you getting at each step of a code